# Email forwarding and tracking with mandrill and django

Tags: python, django, smtp, mailchimp

[Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) is a fairly new transactional email service from the makers of [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/).  I would like to use this service to track emails for clients.

Similar to [this question about a rails implementation of tracking and forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078885/email-forwarding-like-craigslist-rails), my Django application would provide each user with a unique email address, and any emails sent to that address would be tracked by Mandrill automatically, and that tracking data would then be provided to users in a nice interface.

I know Mandrill [can act as an SMTP server](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/20689696-smtp-integration).  I don't know a lot about this, but I know that this means it is at least possible to read an email and compose an email.  Since Mandrill can track incoming emails this handles pretty much everything I need.

Is there a better way to do this?  Ideally I'd like to simply forward the message unaltered and just track it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, but I am willing to edit it to make it more "on topic".  What I was hoping for was an actual suggestion for an implementation scheme considering both the options available through Mandrill's api and general SMTP capabilities.

Comment: I agree seems like folks are unaware of Mandrill which is a new system implemented by Mailchimp. Infact Mandrill would soon need its own tag, thus it would never be offtopic. Maybe there is some other reason to close this as offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at https://mandrillapp.com/ , it gives you everything you need for Tracking whats happening with each email. Also the https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/ Api has all the various functions and lets you retrieve data from your app. What worked for me was just playing with this and checking on what options are available. Also the Mandrill Customer support is very good is getting back on various queries thus try that as well.
http://help.mandrill.com/anonymous_requests/new

Is there anything in particular you would like to track?