# How to do Cragislist email forwarding in Node.js (receive email to auto-generated email address and forward it)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, craigslist

All I found was this SO question using Rails: [Email Forwarding like Craigslist - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078885/email-forwarding-like-craigslist-rails)

I googled for a long time but could not find anything using Node.js.

I know this is not the typically accepted SO question, but I literally have no other recourse at this point.

Could you please point me to a resource I could use or some tutorial ? Or maybe you know yourself how to do this ?

EDIT: I ended up using Sendgrid.

Comment: What do you mean with "Cragislist email forwarding"? Do you want to receive mail in node.js?

Comment: @thezadmin I already use NodeMailer to send emails, but I cannot use it to forward emails received to a randomly generated address if I am not mistaken ?

Comment: @some Craigslist auto-generates a random email for each seller to protect the real email address of a seller. When an email is sent to the randomly generated email, it is forwarded to the real email address.

Comment: @TheProgrammer - sorry I misunderstood the question, sorry about that, thought it was just sending from randomized email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal cases you have a mailserver that receives the email.

I ***strongly recommend*** that you do that, because there are so many things a competent smtp-server handle, that you don't want to re-implement yourself. The smtp-server can then call your program to handle the received mails.

If you *really really* want to implement a smtp-server for incoming mail in node.js, you can have a look at [mailin](https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin). It was last updated in August 2017, but have some issues with 2048 bit DKIM keys and some other things.

*I have not used it myself, but according to the description it does what you are asking for.*

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly: "In normal cases you have a mailserver that receives the email.", can't I have a mailserver that is coded using node.js ? Or is it something entirely different ?

Comment: @TheProgrammer You could write a mailserver (smtp-server) in node.js if you want, but I really really really really really really really really seriously don't recommend it.There are so many things that can go wrong, and you will spend days being frustrated, and you will also loose incoming mails when your program fails. I recommend that you use a real mailserver to receive the mails, and then you can process them with a node-script.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is exactly "a real mailserver" ?

Comment: @TheProgrammer Something that is used by thousand sites daily, exmaple: postfix, exim, sendmail...

Comment: If I was going to do something like what you want to do, I would probably setup a [postfix-mail-server](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html), and setup virtual hosting with the configuration in a database. That way I only need to update the database.

Comment: The link does not provide me with the necessary information to accomplish what my question describes ? It only explains a few very basic uses of postfix from my understanding and certainly not enough info for someone who has never set up a SMTP server before :/ I still can't find a good tutorial.